# Top n results based on value and ASCII sorting

Tags: python

I have a dict of letters and their occurrence: `sents = {'a': 2, 'y': 10, 'x': 10, 'b': 10, 'v': 10, 'g': 8}`, I want to return the top 3 letters based on occurrence, now if a letter occurs the same as another return the letter that has the smallest ascii (like when it is sorted) (these letters can be actual sentences or words).

**The problem**:

Currently I am getting the dicts values and sorting them, getting the top 3. the problem is that I can get something like `[10,10,10]`, with this I have to now sort the sentences using their ascii codes. The issue is that I don't want to look up the sentences that have the value `10` 3 times, so I can put it in a set to give me only `1` 10, I will then look up the top 3 sentences based off 2 criteria, they have the value `10` and their ascii order.

Currently this is my code to do that:

```
def __getTopRes__(self, sents):
    #get the top 3 keys, if they have multiple of the same make it a set to remove dupes, then loop over each one
    top = sorted(list(set(sorted(list(sents.values()), reverse=True)[:3])),reverse=True)
    ret = []
    #for each value, check the dict for all the strings that have that key
    #sort each key by alphabetical order
    for t in top:
        ret.extend(sorted([k for k,v in sents.items() if t == v]))
    #return top 3 sorted results
    return ret[:3]
```

I should get the top 3 letters of `[b,v,x]`
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you do `sorted(list(...))` instead of just `sorted(...)`? Makes it rather harder to read...

Comment: @HeapOverflow I wasn't sure that sorted worked on a set, but I guess it works on any iterable?

Comment: Well, any finite iterable whose elements allow sorting. For example `sorted((object(), object()))` will crash because the objects don't support `<` comparison. But applying `list(...)` doesn't change that.

Comment: @Kevin: `sorted` is equivalent to `tmp = list(iterable); tmp.sort(restofargs); return tmp`; the very first step is `list`-ifying.

Comment: Is `__getTopRes__` a method from a class? Why the double underscores and camelCase?

Comment: @AMC Honestly, I am not entirly sure why I did it this way, Can you point me in the right direction as to where the convention is and when I should use double underscore and camel case?

Comment: @Kevin [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the reference when it comes to Python style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> sorted(sents, key=lambda s: (-sents[s], s))[:3]
['b', 'v', 'x']
```

Sorts primarily by number of occurrences (the negation makes it descending) and in case of ties by the "letter". Then just take the first three.

Alternatively, sort first by "letter" and then sort by number of occurrences in reverse (this works because `sorted` is stable).

```
>>> sorted(sorted(sents), key=sents.get, reverse=True)[:3]
['b', 'v', 'x']
```

Comment: Would you mind just explaining/describing the code?

Comment: @Kevin I wrote a bit, though wasn't sure what, as I merely coded your specified logic.

Comment: So, what's being done here happens on a compiler level. Python is designed such that when two tuples are compared, the first value is observed and if they are equal, then the next value is observed, etc. until a conclusion (true or false) can be reached. That's what the sorted() function is doing here, comparing tuples.

Comment: _the negation makes it descending_ Can’t you use the `reverse=True` argument, or am I missing something?

Comment: @AMC That would then also apply to the "letters" and thus give an undesired order.

Comment: @AMC But I now added a solution that does use `reverse=True` in a way that works.